# While running Flutter For Web app where flutter is unable to resolve the dependencies. Process ends with exit code 69

Tags: flutter

I am trying out Flutter For Web technical preview but when I created the Flutter Web app it is showing following message while resolving dependencies:

```
[FlutterForWebDemoApp] pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: git fetch
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
exit code 69
```

here is the pubspec.yaml file of project:

```
name: flutterwebdemo
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: where you entered `pub get` command?

Comment: is it your app or one of samples from `flutter_web/examples` folder?

Comment: When I pressed f5 in VS code pub get showed up in the output tab, I did not enter pub get manually. I am following this example: https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterForWebDemoApp

Comment: did you try some samples from `flutter_web/examples` folder first?

Comment: I just did tried running one project from that and it ran fine, the path for flutter_web and flutter_web_ui is given that of local.

Comment: so compare those two `pubspec.yaml` files from both projects and check where they differ

Comment: It worked, I changed the path of flutter_web and flutter_web_ui to the local packages of respective folders and it is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the Flutter for web master repo from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/)and copied the all three folders from packages folder ie flutter_web, flutter_web_ui and flutter_web_test into flutter's main packages folder and set that path in the pubspec.yaml and after that everything is working fine.

Here is the new pubspec.yaml after changes:

```
name: flutter_for_web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    path: C:\flutter\packages\flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    path: C:\flutter\packages\flutter_web_ui
```

Comment: getting "The 'path' field of the description must be relative."